# lines of bearing bounding a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfWP5.jpg)

Given a circle of radius R, that is D units from the origin, I would like to find a method for finding the two lines of bearing from the origin that are tangent to to the circle.

This is not a homework assignment. I don't want the answer spelled out, I'd rather be pointed in the direction of it, such as what formulas to use; I don't even know where to start. In fact, the more vague your answer is, the better it will probably be.

In case it helps to explain, use the following values in examples: R = 1, D = 10; but I would like to find a general algorithm that will work for a circle of any arbitrary size and distance from the origin (and it doesn't have to be in the first quadrant, that was just to keep the image size down).

I was unable to find a similar question using search, but apologies in advance if this has been asked before. I'll close the question right away if it has.

Comment: First find the equation of a line to the center of the circle. Then draw some pictures and use a theorem of an old greek guy.

Comment: can it be done entirely non-graphically?

Comment: The pictures are just to help you see what is going on. I do not think any derivation will actually use them

Comment: ok, thank you. the reason i ask is that i am trying to conceive of an algorithm for the problem that will allow for automation.

Comment: $M$, $R$, $D$ forms one right triangle, and $L$, $R$, $D$ another, with $D$ being the hypotenuse, because $M$ and $L$ are tangent to the circle (touch the circle at a single point). Because the two triangles have two edges and all three angles the same, the third edges must also be same, thus $M=L$. Finding their length is the same problem as the one stated by question *"How far is the horizon, if your eyes are at height $D-R$ above the surface of a sphere (or circle) of radius $R$?".

Comment: Very good, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a circle $\Gamma'$ whose diameter is given by the origin and the centre of your circle $\Gamma$. 
The intersections between $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ give the points of tangency: can you prove why?

Comment: i think i see why this works, but i doubt that i could prove it. thanks though, this should give me something to work on.